# WCF client: This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF self-hosted:

```
        var localEndPoint = GetLocalEndPoint();
        var host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Server), new Uri(localEndPoint));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServer), new WebHttpBinding
        {
            SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
            ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
            OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
            CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,10,0),
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,ReaderQuotas = XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max
        }, "");
        var stp = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        stp.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;
        stp.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

        ServiceThrottlingBehavior stb = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = Int32.MaxValue,
            MaxConcurrentInstances = Int32.MaxValue,
            MaxConcurrentSessions = Int32.MaxValue
        };
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(stb);

        ContractDescription cd = host.Description.Endpoints[0].Contract;

        OperationDescription myOperationDescription = cd.Operations.Find("Send");

        DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior serializerBehavior =

            myOperationDescription.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
        if (serializerBehavior == null)
        {
            serializerBehavior =
                new DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(myOperationDescription)
                {
                    MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647
                };

            myOperationDescription.Behaviors.Add(serializerBehavior);
        }
        else
        {
            serializerBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647;
        }

        host.Open();
```

Here is the code to request to WCF service:

```
public string GetQuote()
{
 using (ChannelFactory<IServer> cf =
                new ChannelFactory<IServer>(new WebHttpBinding
                {
                    SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
                    ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
                    OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
                    CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
                    MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
                    MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                    ReaderQuotas = XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max
                }, string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", StreamInsightConfiguration.Default.SocketServerHost,
                    StreamInsightConfiguration.Default.SocketPort)))
            {
                cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior
                {
                    FaultExceptionEnabled = true                        
                });

                foreach (OperationDescription op in cf.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
                {
                    DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dataContractBehavior = op.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>() as DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior;
                    if (dataContractBehavior != null)
                    {
                        dataContractBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647;
                    }
                }


                IServer channel = cf.CreateChannel();

                var result = channel.GetQuote(getQuoteRequested);


                return result;
            }
}
```

I have an exception when make a multiple requests to WCF service.

The exception is:

*An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://192.168.2.101:11000/GetQuote. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.*

Note that: I make 2000 GetQuote requests at the same time. At the time I have exception, the WCF server doesn't have any exception
So could you please help me to resolve this issue?